# Aws rekognition passing image using variable not working

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

```
$rekognition = new RekognitionClient([
'version' => 'latest',
'region'  => 'us-west-2',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => '....................',
    'secret' => '....................'
]
]);




$source2=json_encode($source);
echo $source2;

$result3=$rekognition->compareFaces([
'SimilarityThreshold' => 70.05,
'SourceImage' => [ 

    'S3Object' => [
        'Bucket' => 'krishrekog',
        'Name' => "david.jpg",             //Here is the problem

    ],
],
'TargetImage' => [ 

    'S3Object' => [
        'Bucket' => 'krishrekog',
        'Name' => 'target.jpg',

    ],
],
]);

$similar=0;



 foreach($result3['FaceMatches'] as $d){
   $similar=$d['Similarity']."<br>";
} 

if($similar>75){
echo "Matching faces!!";
}
else{
echo "Not Matching Faces!!";
}
```

In the above code if I provide the source image as david.jpg it will work with no errors,but if I store image name in a variable and use json_encode and send it as source image.It throws a big error.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What "big error"? Put it in your question. Also, clarify what you mean by storing the image name and encoding it. Put an example of that too.

Comment: Please post the code that has the error, not the code that works.